# How to connect in a visual fashion to MySql that is behind a reverse proxy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, server, mysql-workbench, reverse-proxy

Before of the Rails Kamal-Docker advent I was used to connect from my local machine to the remote MySql production database by using MySql Workbench. Now I've my database on the remote server placed behind a proxy server and probably connecting to the remote database as I was used to is not more possible or at least more complicated.

How one is supposed to connect to the MySql (or other) database in such a case? Maybe, directly in the browser by using a web-based database management tool (e.g. a gem within the Rails app) or something else I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

You can do `kamal app exec -i 'bin/rails dbconsole'`.

That shall work for any database.

Comment: Thank Mikita. Is there any way to connect to the database using tools like MySql Workbench or a web-based database management tool? Using that command one can connect to the database in the console.